# Is there an Event that is triggered when all page controls are loaded and databound?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, devexpress, web-controls, page-lifecycle

I am using the DevExpress suite of web controls and have built a page with a fairly large entry form with textboxes, comboboxes, etc.

I am writing code to randomly generate data to populate this large form with.  I call this code with a line on the Page_Load event but I realize that at the time of the call, anything that has a datasource attached to it (combobox, for example), is not databound yet.

Is there an existing event I can hook into that is called when the all of the page's controls AND datasources are bound?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [PreRenderComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.prerendercomplete?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) page lifecycle event is fired after all controls are loaded and databound.

Comment: Will not work / be raised (PreRender***) on callbacks.

Comment: actually it works perfectly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100) scroll down to prerendercomplete

"Raised after each data bound control whose DataSourceID property is set calls its DataBind method. For more information, see Data Binding Events for Data-Bound Controls later in this topic.".  I didn't ask about callbacks.

Comment: If you have any grid (any callback aware control) on page, try to make any callback (sorting, paging, etc.) to ensure this.